# Why did I always get wrong des-ecb result in nodejs native cipher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, des

Here is my code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
let enterJS = 'h';
let enterStr = null;
enterStr = encrypt(enterJS, 'des-ecb').toUpperCase();
console.log("===============>>>> ENTER STR : " + enterStr);
function encrypt(plaintext, algorithm) {
    var keyStr = "imtestKey";
    var key = new Buffer(keyStr);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    var ciph = cipher.update(plaintext, 'ascii');
    var ciphf = cipher.final();
    return ciph.toString('hex') + ciphf.toString('hex');
}
```

But the result I got is:

> ===============>>>> ENTER STR : 16CE7F2DEB9BB56D

which the right result I test on this web: http://tool.chacuo.net/cryptdes

> des-mode:ecb
>
> fill-mode:pkcs7padding
>
> password:imtestKey
>
> output:hex

The right result (the same with my java code) is

> 832e52ebd3fb9059

My node version is v8.9.0, how can I get the right result?

This is my java code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String js = "h";
        try {
            byte[] bs = encrypt(js.getBytes(), "imtestKey".getBytes());
            System.out.println(byte2hex(bs));
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] src, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey securekey = keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, securekey, sr);
        return cipher.doFinal(src);
    }


    public static String byte2hex(byte[] b) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String stmp = "";

        for(int n = 0; b != null && n < b.length; ++n) {
            stmp = Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 255);
            if (stmp.length() == 1) {
                sb.append("0").append(stmp);
            } else {
                sb.append(stmp);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: The key "imtestKey" is not a correct length, DES requires a key of 8-bytes I length and the provided key is 9-bytes. Also note that the LSB of each byte is ignored.

Comment: @zaph But why I use java,the web tool and crypto-js lib then I can get the right result

Comment: @rustyx Please see my java code below

Comment: If the key is an incorrect length the encryption is undefined. Use a correct key length, 8-bytes for DES.

Comment: @zaph if you said the key is incorrect why can I get the right answer with the web tool and my java code?

Comment: 1. Why are you using an incorrect key, don't. Correct this mistake first. "imtestKey" is 9-characters, DES requires an 8-byte key. 2. The results when providing incorrect inputs can be anything. Each implementation (and the programmer who wrote it) can and will handle incorrect inputs in any manor they decide. 3. There is a good chance you are not proving the inputs I the correct/expected encoding/format such as hex, binary, an incorrect conversion from text to binary.

Comment: 4. DES has a 56-bit key provided as 8-bytes, the LSB was initially used for parity and it now generally ignored. 5. Don't use DES it is not secure, use AES which has essentially the same usage but with longer keys of 128, 192 or 256 bits. 6. Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: 7. Ensure you are using ECB mode on both, the JS code may not be using ECB mode, generally the default is CBC mode. CBC mode with no IV provided again is undefined. See ECB and CBC block modes; [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security aspects aside (as has been pointed out, DES and ECB, as well as no key derivation is insecure), you are using a deprecated [`crypto.createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) function which *derives* a key from the provided password.

> The implementation of `crypto.createCipher()` **derives** keys using the OpenSSL function `EVP_BytesToKey` with the digest algorithm set to **MD5, one iteration, and no salt**. The lack of salt allows dictionary attacks as the same password always creates the same key. The low iteration count and non-cryptographically secure hash algorithm allow passwords to be tested very rapidly.

Use [`crypto.createCipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) instead, which uses the provided key as-is:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
let enterJS = 'h';
let enterStr = null;
function encrypt(plaintext, algorithm) {
    var keyStr = "imtestKey";
    var key = Buffer.alloc(8, keyStr);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, Buffer.alloc(0));
    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    var ciph = cipher.update(Buffer.from(plaintext));
    var ciphf = cipher.final();
    return Buffer.concat([ciph, ciphf]).toString('hex');
}
enterStr = encrypt(enterJS, 'des-ecb').toUpperCase();
console.log("===============>>>> ENTER STR : " + enterStr);
```

The `createCipheriv` API will reject your 9-byte long key, because DES requires an 8-byte key. I made a workaround to take the first 8 bytes from the provided password as the key and now it's printing your desired result.

Output:

```
===============>>>> ENTER STR : 832E52EBD3FB9059
```